Two-agent sequential RL
I have the following RL model that I want to train (see the diagram below). My idea is to have two agents: agent A and agent B. Agent A observes the input I1 and decides an action action1, then immediately, agent B observes the input (action1, I2) where I2=f(action1, I1) is obtained with a known function f(.). Next, agent B decides the action action2. The two actions action1 and action2 are used to compute the reward, which is common for the two agents. The next state of agent A will be obtained I1' and the process continues.
 --------------------------- next state --------------------------------------
|                                                                             |
I1 -> |A| -> action1 ------------------------>|B| -> (action1, action2) -> reward
|                |                             |                
|                |                             |
 -----------------> f(I1, action1) -> I2 ------
 

I want to know if is it possible to implement a DRL algorithm for this model, or more importantly, if there is a similar two-agents model that is proposed that I can use?

Is it important that there are two agents, or this just a way to explain that there are two different data structures for the two different decisions? I cannot see anything that makes this strictly a two agent problem. Is there any data that must remain hidden between the steps (e.g. for agent/step B, the agent is not allowed to know I1 (and I guess f() is not reversible if so), or some other reason why you need to view this as two agents?

@NeilSlater agree, the most important part imho is what is $f$ (and thus its properties)

It is not important to see it as two agents. Let's say we model it as a single agent problem. What will be the input state? Only I1? How can I add I2 into the input when I don't know I2 unless I know action1 (since I know f() and I1 and to obtain I2 I need action1) ?
